# Facebook Login fails to build

Tags: facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm developing an App which requires facebook login. The app could build easily when I didn't had implemented the facebook login.

After implementing it, the app cannot build and it doesn't give me a clear error.
I've already added the facebook plugin "Facebook Connect" to my project.

Here's my code:

```
  if(window.navigator.onLine)
    {
   setTimeout(function(){
    var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
                console.log("UserInfo: ", userData);
                }

                facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"], fbLoginSuccess,
                  function loginError (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                  }
              );
},500);
}
```

On the plugin I already set the correct AppId and AppName.

When I try to test, by building it, nothing happens. It gives me an error when I try to upload it. But it doesn't say cleary what is the error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [read more here](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login( ["public_profile","email"],function (response) {
                if(response.authResponse.userID!=''){
                    facebookConnectPlugin.api(response.authResponse.userID+"/?fields=id,email,first_name", ["public_profile"],
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                }    
                }, 
                function (response) {   
                        console.log(response);
               });
```

let me know if its not working